# Failed to create thumb image in $_FILES loop

Tags: php, codeigniter, imagelibrary

I iterate through $_FILES to create thumb images of uploaded pictures. It works fine for the first image but fails for the following pictures. Do I miss to add a special line or there is flow in my code?

Note: Original files gets uploaded successfully and exist in folder before creating thumb out of them.

When I echo error, I get this: "*Your server does not support the GD function required to process this type of image.*". When I upload it on its own, it works!!!!

Thanks

```
public function upload_image()
{
    $config['upload_path']      = './web/uploads/images/';
    $config['allowed_types']    = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size']         = 5120;
    $config['max_width']        = '0';
    $config['max_height']       = '0';
    $config['encrypt_name']     = true;

    $this->load->library('upload');
    $this->upload->initialize($config);     

   foreach ($_FILES as $file => $value)
   {
      $this->upload->do_upload($file);

      $result = $this->upload->data();

      if ($this->manipulate_image($result['file_name']) === false)
      {
          echo 'Failed to create thumb for the image ' . $value['name'] . '<br />';
      }
   }
}

    public function manipulate_image($file_name)
    {
        $config['image_library']    = 'gd2';
        $config['source_image']     = './web/uploads/images/' . $file_name;
        $config['create_thumb']     = true;
        $config['maintain_ratio']   = false;
        $config['width']            = 100;
        $config['height']           = 100;
        //$config['master_dim']     = 'width';
        $config['thumb_marker']     = '_thumb';

        $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);

        if (! $this->image_lib->resize())
        {
            $this->image_lib->clear();
            return false;
        }

        $this->image_lib->clear();
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: what you are getting `var_dump($result)` for each files ?

Comment: array full of data belong to files. It looks fine too. Nothing missing for any files.

Comment: Have you tried to `load` the library only once and using `$this->image_lib->initialize($config);` in the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two things, first, I would move the `load` on the library outside of the `foreach` loop then use `initialize` inside the loop to set the config:

```
$this->image_lib->initialize($config);
```

Also, as documented [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/image_lib.html) you can use

```
echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
```

To get more insight on your problem

Answer (score 0):

Apparently loading loading image_lib multiple times in a loop causes this problem.

Solved without including in loop.